# How to create an HTML attribute without a value using HTML::Element

Tags: html, perl

How can I create an HTML element with an attribute that lacks a value using [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element)?

For example, the `checked` attribute usually doesn't have a value, like this:

```
<input checked name="field" type="checkbox" />
```

The example below, however, gives us a `checked` attribute with an empty string as the value:

```
<input checked="" name="field" type="checkbox" />
```

Code:

```
use HTML::Element;
my $h = HTML::Element->new ( 'input' );

$h->attr ( type => 'checkbox' );
$h->attr ( name => 'field' );
$h->attr ( checked => '' );

print STDOUT $h->as_HTML, "\n";
```

Comment: "the checked attribute usually doesn't have any value" The value is optional for boolean HTML attributes. You can do either `checked="checked"` or simply `checked`.

Comment: You're not answering my question.

Comment: I'm saying you can do `$h->attr ( checked => 'checked' );` to get equivalent HTML to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: ThisSuitIsBlackNot has the correct solution above:

```
$h->attr ( checked => 'checked' );
```

that works.  If he adds it as an answer, I'll delete mine.  Not sure how one could derive that from the documentation, however...  If it is out there somewhere, I would love to have someone point me to it.

OLD SOLUTION:
Not a perfect solution, but I got it to work doing the following:

```
use HTML::Element;
my $h = HTML::Element->new ( 'input', 'checked' );

$h->attr ( type => 'checkbox' );
$h->attr ( name => 'field' );

print STDOUT $h->as_HTML, "\n";
```

which produces this:

```
<input checked name="field" type="checkbox" />
```

but there must be a better way of doing this....

The CPAN documentation states the following:

> Note that setting an attribute to undef (as opposed to "", the empty
>   string) actually deletes the attribute.

which is the reason `$h->attr ('checked');` doesn't work, but there must be a way to add a non-value attribute after element creation.   It's just not obvious (at least to me) on how to do it.